# Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7.0 not powering on and unable to do factory reset

Tags: factory-reset, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7

What happened is my tablet froze. I tried to restart the tablet by holding the power button, however it stayed on the Samsung screen and did not proceed to the home screen. Eventually I was able to turn off the device.

I want to factory reset the device now. However the options to factory reset are not showing. I press and hold volume up together with the power button, nothing happened. What else can I do to hard reset the device?

Comment: Hold the **Volume Down** and **Power Button** to get into the stock recovery - you should be able to do a factory reset from there.

Comment: I tried doing that. Nothing happened.

Comment: Reflashing your stock firmware might help - go into the download mode by pressing Vol Up + Power Button, [Select and download the firmware](http://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/database/GT-P3100/). This is for the Galaxy Tab2 GT-P3100, if this does not match your device then search for an other firmware. Follow the instructions on the bottom of the download-page to reflash a stock rom.